# Lua how to access specific data in a nested table

Tags: lua, nested, lua-table

I parsed some data from a CSV file to a Lua table.

Lets say the table looks like this just bigger

```
tab {
     { id = 1761, anotherID=2, ping=pong}
     { id = 2071, anotherID=4, ping=notpong}
}
```

Now I want to know every ID (without displaying any other data yet) to store them in another table for some time.

I am completely lost here for now..

Using what you wrote I rewrote it a bit and went to have:

```
minitab = {}
        for i, value in ipairs(tab) do
            local id = value.id
            local anotherID = value.anotherID
            minitab[id] = anotherID
        end
```

Would that work? In fact i later want to get just 2 values of a way larger array (around 30 datas) - but I can only push a single array to a GUI dropdown. I want to save the ID as a key and the "anotherID" value wich will be a text after that key so if a ask for the 2071st value it displays the "name" 4

Answer (score 0):

The code below stores the ids as keys in another table:

```
id={}
for k,v in ipairs(tab) do
  id[v.id]=true
end
```

You can then traverse `id` with `pairs` to list the ids.

If you want to remember where each id came from, use `id[v.id]=k` in the loop.

Comment: Worked a bit with that, replaced k,v with i, value - If i want to save 2 variables now in a table format of minitab { 1761 = 2, 2071 = 4 } - how would i go about that? Gonna edit the question, comment code isnt good :D

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you can use this code to traverse your data table `tab` and get `minitab` to be used for your GUI array:

```
--data
tab = {
  {id = "4204", label = "2", desc = "Roancyme"},
  {id = "5517", label = "9", desc = "Bicktuft"},
  {id = "1035", label = "3", desc = "Pipyalum"},
}

--temporary table
local minitab = {}
for i, option in ipairs(tab) do
  minitab[option.id] = option.label
end

--print minitab
print('<select>')
for id, label in pairs(minitab) do
  print(string.format('<option value="%s">%s</option>', id, label)) --> <option value="1035">3</option>
end
print('</select>')
print()
```

However, I don't think it is necessary to create a temporary table to store those values, because you can easily traverse your original table `tab` and directly pull out the output you need; like this:

```
--print directly from tab
print('<select>')
for i, option in ipairs(tab) do
  print(string.format('<option value="%s">%s</option>', option.id, option.label)) --> <option value="1035">3</option>
end
print('</select>')
print()
```

Unless you need to work with it before displaying the list on the drop down (e.g. add some prefix to the `label`, sort `minitab` by the label, etc); but you don't want to disturb the original data table `tab`. In this case, it would make sense to use the temporary table.

```
--format values in temporary table
local minitab = {}
for i, option in ipairs(tab) do
  local minitabID = option.id
  local minitabLabel = string.format('Item %s - %s', option.label, option.desc)
  table.insert(minitab, {id = minitabID, label = minitabLabel})
end

--sort temporary table
table.sort(minitab, function (o1, o2) return o2.label > o1. label end)

--print formatted values from temporary table
print('<select>')
for i, option in ipairs(minitab) do
  print(string.format('<option value="%s">%s</option>', option.id, option.label)) --> <option value="4204">Item 2 - Roancyme</option>
end
print('</select>')
```

NB: Please take a note on which table iteration uses `ipairs` and which one uses `pairs`. See the complete code snippet [here](https://eval.in/742013).